# PostgreSQL SQl SP getting Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type Int16Handler error

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures

In my PostgreSQL database SP execution code like this (generated through pgAdmin4)

```
CALL s_pc_efo_operation.s_p_efo_pmdnumber(
    <IN locationcode smallint>, 
    <IN measureddatetime timestamp without time zone>, 
    <IN makerpackerid character varying>, 
    <INOUT pc_pmdoperationid bigint>, 
    <INOUT pc_pmdoperationnumber text>
)
```

I'm trying to execute it through my c# application like this.

```
try
{
    await _dataService.BeginTransactionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    _dataService.InitializeCommand("CALL s_pc_efo_operation.s_p_efo_pmdnumber(@locationcode,@measureddatetime,@makerpackerid,@pc_pmdoperationid,@pc_pmdoperationnumber)", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    _dataService.AttachParameter("@locationcode", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Smallint, (int)locationCode);
    _dataService.AttachParameter("@measureddatetime", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, date);
    _dataService.AttachParameter("@makerpackerid", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char, makerID);
    _dataService.AttachParameter("@pc_pmdoperationid", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint, ParameterDirection.InputOutput, "pc_pmdoperationid");
    _dataService.AttachParameter("@pc_pmdoperationnumber", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text, ParameterDirection.InputOutput, "pc_pmdoperationnumber");

    NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = await _dataService.ExecuteDataReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

}
catch (Exception ez)
{

    throw ez;
}
```

in the above code gives me this error.

**`Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type Int16Handler`**

in the debug mode, these parameters values as like this,

```
Date = {2/1/2010 12:00:00 AM}
(int)locationCode = 4
makerID = "-1"
```

Comment: Can you identify which line of your code threw the exception? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones getting in this line `NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = await _dataService.ExecuteDataReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`